# Different sql query for each input

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a input and I want to run some sql queries when input submitted.
But I want to run different sql queries for each input. For example if I put my `<?php echo $value['id'][$i]; ?>` code near the input, it shows id's like in this image.
[Input Id's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAEeH.png)

My **input form** is like this:

```
<form action='' method='POST' style="margin-top: 213px;">   
<input type='submit' name='submit'/><?php echo $value['id'][$i]; ?>
</form>
```

My **if** code is like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$wpdb->update( $wpdb->options, array("option_value" => "ff0000"), array("option_name" => "theme-bg"), array("%s"), array("%s") );    }
```

I want to edit if code and run different sql queries for each input button.
I hope I could explain my question.

Thanks for reading it.

Edit1: My whole code;

```
                        <?php
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach ($value['options'] as $box):
                        $checked = '';
                        $class = '';
                        $img_size = '';


                        if ($value['image_size'][$i])
                            $img_size = 'width="' . $value['image_size'][$i] . '"';
                        else if ($value['image_size'][$i] == false && $value['image_size'][0] == true)
                            $img_size = 'width="' . $value['image_size'][0] . '"';
                        else
                            $img_size = 'width=""';




                        if (get_option($value['id'][$i])) {
                            if (get_option($value['id'][$i]) == 'true') {
                                $checked = ' checked="checked"';
                                $class = ' acesra-img-selected';
                            }
                        } elseif ($value['default'][$i] == "checked") {
                            $class = ' acesra-img-selected';
                            $checked = ' checked="checked"';
                        }
                        ?>
                        <label class="self-theme-select<?php echo $class; ?>" for="<?php echo $value['id'][$i]; ?>">
                            <img  src="<?php echo $value['image_src'][$i]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $box ?>" />
                            <input class="acera-image-checkbox-b"  type="checkbox"<?php echo $checked; ?> name="<?php echo $value['id'][$i]; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id'][$i]; ?>" />
                            <?php if ($value['show_labels'] == "true"): ?><p><?php echo $box; ?></p><?php endif; ?>
                            <form action='' method='POST' style="margin-top: 213px;">   
                                <input type='submit' name='submit'/><?php echo $value['id'][$i]; ?>
                        </form>
                        </label>
                        <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                            $wpdb->update( $wpdb->options, array("option_value" => "ff0000"), array("option_name" => "tema-bg"), array("%s"), array("%s") );
                            }  ?>

                        <?php
                        $i++;
                    endforeach;
                    ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: Hello. I believe that your image is wrong. I'm Right?

Comment: Actually, no. It should be like that, input button under every image, and different sql queries for each of them.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
<form action='' method='POST' style="margin-top: 213px;">   
<input type='submit' name='submit1'/><?php echo $value['id'][$i]; ?>
<input type='submit' name='submit2'/><?php echo $value['id'][$i]; ?>
<input type='submit' name='submit3'/><?php echo $value['id'][$i]; ?>
</form>
```

And then:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
$wpdb->update( $wpdb->options, array("option_value" => "ff0000"), array("option_name" => "theme-bg"), array("%s"), array("%s") );    } 
elseif(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
//another query for submit2
} 
elseif(isset($_POST['submit3'])){
//another query for submit3
}
```

**Edited** for your code

Changed this line:

```
<input type='submit' name='submit<?php echo $i ?>'/><?php echo $value['id'][$i]; ?>
```

Here we dynamically create value for name attribute

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($value['options'] as $box):
$checked = '';
$class = '';
$img_size = '';

if ($value['image_size'][$i])
    $img_size = 'width="' . $value['image_size'][$i] . '"';
else if ($value['image_size'][$i] == false && $value['image_size'][0] == true)
    $img_size = 'width="' . $value['image_size'][0] . '"';
else
    $img_size = 'width=""';

if (get_option($value['id'][$i])) {
    if (get_option($value['id'][$i]) == 'true') {
        $checked = ' checked="checked"';
        $class = ' acesra-img-selected';
    }
} elseif ($value['default'][$i] == "checked") {
    $class = ' acesra-img-selected';
    $checked = ' checked="checked"';
}
?>

<label class="self-theme-select<?php echo $class; ?>" for="<?php echo $value['id'][$i]; ?>">
    <img  src="<?php echo $value['image_src'][$i]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $box ?>" />
    <input class="acera-image-checkbox-b"  type="checkbox"<?php echo $checked; ?> name="<?php echo $value['id'][$i]; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id'][$i]; ?>" />
    <?php if ($value['show_labels'] == "true"): ?><p><?php echo $box; ?></p><?php endif; ?>
    <form action='' method='POST' style="margin-top: 213px;">
        <input type='submit' name='submit<?php echo $i ?>'/><?php echo $value['id'][$i]; ?>
    </form>
</label>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit0'])){
    $wpdb->update( $wpdb->options, array("option_value" => "ff0000"), array("option_name" => "tema-bg"), array("%s"), array("%s") );
}elseif(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    // query for submit1
}elseif(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
    // query for submit2
}elseif(isset($_POST['submit3'])){
    // query for submit3
}
?>

<?php
$i++;
endforeach;
?>
</div>
```

I've also edited this block:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit0'])){
    $wpdb->update( $wpdb->options, array("option_value" => "ff0000"), array("option_name" => "tema-bg"), array("%s"), array("%s") );
}elseif(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    // query for submit1
}elseif(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
    // query for submit2
}elseif(isset($_POST['submit3'])){
    // query for submit3
}
?>
```

But this one can be adapted to your foreach loop probably.
Something like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'.$i])){ // adding $i here
    $wpdb->update( $wpdb->options, array("option_value" => "ff0000"), array("option_name" => "tema-bg"), array("%s"), array("%s") );
}
?>
```

Though it depends on how exactly your queries differ for each case of submit.

Comment: Hello Timoxa, thanks for your answer. But if I do like that its becoming like this. [link](http://prntscr.com/f4mx5t)
I am adding my whole code now for better explain.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think this logic will work but I got error.
 Fatal error: Call to a member function update() on null in ...

Comment: You're welcome. For this error check your `$wpdb` variable for whether it was initialized and what value it holds.

Comment: I added `global $wpdb;` before the $wpdb and its solved.
Thank you so much again, I appreciate for your help <3

Comment: No problem :) Good luck!